# Always render default component whenever the router links is clicked

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am using Vue and Vue-router.

routes

```
{
    path: '/admin', component: AdminPage,
    children: [
        {path: 'admin-user', component: AdminUser, name: 'admin-user'}
    ]
},
```

In the `AdminPage` component I have router links and its router view to navigate between pages. One of the route is of path `admin-user`, which uses the `AdminUser` component.

AdminPage.vue:

```
<template>
    <div id="adminPage">
        <ul id="adminNavList">
            <li>... some nav links ...</li>
            <li><router-link :to="{ name: 'admin-user', params: {front: true}}">User</router-link></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="adminViewPort" v-if="isAdmin">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

In the `AdminUser` component there are two components which are displayed based on the conditions. When the route path is first loaded and the `AdminUser` is created, the `AdminUserList` component is displayed by default. And when clicks the button which fires `show_user_bookings()` button, the other component `AdminUserBookings` is displayed. Similarly when the user clicks the button which fires `show_user_list()` method, the `AdminUserList` component is displayed.

AdminUser.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="AdminUserWrapper">
        <admin-user-list v-if="component_name==='user_list'" :showUserBookings="show_user_bookings"></admin-user-list>
        <admin-user-bookings v-if="component_name==='user_bookings'" :show_user_list="show_user_list"></admin-user-bookings>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import AdminUserList from './AdminUserList.vue'
    import AdminUserBookings from './AdminUserBookings.vue';

    export default {
        name: 'AdminUserWrapper',
        components: {
            AdminUserList, AdminUserBookings
        },
        data() {
            return {
                component_name: '',
        },
        methods: {
            show_user_list() {
                this.component_name = 'user_list';
            },
            show_user_bookings() {
                this.component_name = 'user_bookings';
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.show_user_list();
        }
    }
</script>
```

So the problem is, if `AdminUserBookings` component is displayed and clicks the link for the path `admin-user`, the default component `AdminUserList` is not displayed. Is there any way to display the default component `AdminUserList` whenever the `admin-user` path is requested from the `AdminPage` even if its already in the `admin-user` path when the `AdminUserBookings` component is displayed?

Comment: can't test right now, but I think you could initialize `data` with `component_name: 'user_list'` instead of the empty string, to show that component by default.

Comment: @LuisOrduz This is what the `show_user_list()` method is doing when the `AdminPage` is created. It's calling the `show_user_list()` method on its (`AdminPage` component) `created()` method.